# Excel VBA: how to check if a file exists using Administrative share path

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I’m trying to create a deployment tool using excel and VBA.
The spreadsheet contains an Administrative share path i.e. (\\G5RCJ55\C$\users\public\desktop\file.txt)
I have administrative rights. I pull the path using VBA and tried using dir() but that fails.

Any suggestions on how I can:
1.  Check if a file exists
2.  If not, copy a file to the target machine/directory (The public desktop on the C: Drive).

[image]

```
Sub deployToDesktop(cnt As Integer)
   Dim fullPath As String: fullPath = Cells(cnt, "D").value & "\" & Cells(cnt, "E").value

   MsgBox ("Admin path " & fullPath)

   If Not Dir(fullPath) Then
      MsgBox (fullPath)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you got administrative rights for the other pc as well and is the share for c: on the other pc managed and the rights set?

Comment: Yes, I've the correct rights. Can I use file explorer to manually do all this but want to automate the process.

Comment: The error message I get when running the code: run-time error '52': Bad file name or number

Comment: What line does the error come?

Comment: If Dir(fullPath) Then

Answer (score 2):

OK Found an answer. I need to use the FileSystemObject.  This understands UNC path files.
Here is the updated code:

```
Sub deployToDesktop(cnt As Integer)
   Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

   Dim fullPath As String: fullPath = Cells(cnt, "D").value & "\"

   If fso.FolderExists(fullPath) Then
      MsgBox ("Exists " & fullPath)
   End If
End Sub
```